# How to divide a 2D irregular shape into small cells?

Tags: python, image, 2d

How to divide a 2D irregular shape into small cells, like in the image? The black and white image is the irregular shape and the green line represents the outline of the divided cells, like this:

[image: Example]

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901283/webgl-and-tessellation-library

Comment: Thanks. It does help, but it's not really the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: You might want to either:
Divide the shape into something that tiles (squares, triangles, etc.)
or potentially use a kind of voronoi diagram if you want a more "organic" feel

Comment: What output format is needed?

Comment: a labelled mask with each cell labelled using different colors.

Comment: i actually found a very useful solution, but i'm not sure if i can code it
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321021/splitting-polygon-into-equal-area-polygons-using-qgis